# Is Blevins in All the Pretty Horses the modern-day version of Blood Meridian's The Kid?

Tags: cormac-mccarthy, blood-meridian, all-the-pretty-horses

Both The Kid and Blevins are not evil but at the same time extremely dangerous young men (of roughly the same age) on their own due to the death of their fathers.

It seems pretty likely that if Blevins had been transported to the less-civilized time of almost exactly a century before the time of *All the Pretty Horses* (1840s vs 1940s) he might have ended up in a group like Glantons. The Kid was murderous, even before joining Glanton and Blevins also showed the same quick temper and murderousness in roughly the same part of the world where The Kid ended up.

I would say that The Kid was much more reserved and self-contained than Blevins but he lived in a time when that was more necessary.

Is Blevins in All the Pretty Horses the modern-day version of Blood Meridian's The Kid?